# Swiper carousel IE11 bug: images are overstretched

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11, swiper.js

I have put together a carousel with the help pf the Swiper plugin. It works fine, with no bugs,except in **Internet Explorer 11**, on **Windows 10**. Here, the images are overstretched vertically:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   slidesPerView: 4,
   spaceBetween: 20,
   pagination: {
     el: '.swiper-pagination',
     loop: true,
     draggable: true,
     clickable: true
   },
   autoplay: {
     delay: 2000,
     disableOnInteraction: true,
   },
   breakpoints: {
     1024: {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 20,
     },
     768: {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 20,
     },
     640: {
       slidesPerView: 2,
       spaceBetween: 10,
     },
     480: {
       slidesPerView: 1,
       spaceBetween: 10,
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.swiper-slide {
    height: auto !important;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swiper-container col-sm-12">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

What is the cause of this bug? How can it be fixed?

UPDATE - screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Put the images in fixed width divs, and make the width of the images 100%.

Comment: @Teemu this makes the images ok, but the slides (carousel items), remain overstretched.

Comment: could you post an image of what you mean by *the images are overstretched vertically* ?

Comment: @Towkir I added a scree-short...

Comment: Since the parent of the <img> tag uses "Flex-box" (d-flex flex-column) make sure that IE11 understand Flex-box. If not then you have to use "position" specially "absolute" as a work around. I do not have access to IE11 but it should be an easy  fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wrapped the images in a `<div class="picture-container"></div>`and that is an improvement, but not an optimal solution yet:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
   slidesPerView: 4,
   spaceBetween: 20,
   pagination: {
     el: '.swiper-pagination',
     loop: true,
     draggable: true,
     clickable: true
   },
   autoplay: {
     delay: 2000,
     disableOnInteraction: true,
   },
   breakpoints: {
     1024: {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 20,
     },
     768: {
       slidesPerView: 3,
       spaceBetween: 20,
     },
     640: {
       slidesPerView: 2,
       spaceBetween: 10,
     },
     480: {
       slidesPerView: 1,
       spaceBetween: 10,
     }
   }
 });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.swiper-slide {
    height: auto !important;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="swiper-container col-sm-12">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide d-flex flex-column bg-light">
          <div class="picture-container"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/600" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
          <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
            <h4 class="m-0">Lorem ipsum dolor</h4>
            <h5 class="small">Aliquam voluptates, quisquam illum.</h5>
            <p class="card-text ">Fugiat itaque doloremque assumenda vitae, consequatur aspernatur! Porro eum, vitae!</p>
            <div class="mt-auto">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```